# How to retrieve all errors and messages from a query using ADO

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, ado

When a SQL batch returns more than one message from e.g. print statements, then I can only retrieve the first one using the ADO connection's Errors collection. How do I get the rest of the messages?

If I run this script:

```
Option Explicit
Dim conn
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Provider = "SQLOLEDB"
conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(local);Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=Master"
conn.Open

conn.Execute("print 'Foo'" & vbCrLf & "print 'Bar'" & vbCrLf & "raiserror ('xyz', 10, 127)")

Dim error
For Each error in conn.Errors
    MsgBox error.Description
Next
```

Then I only get "Foo" back, never "Bar" or "xyz".

Is there a way to get the remaining messages?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured it out on my own.

This works:

```
Option Explicit
Dim conn
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Provider = "SQLOLEDB"
conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(local);Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=Master"
conn.Open

Dim rs
Set rs = conn.Execute("print 'Foo'" & vbCrLf & "print 'Bar'" & vbCrLf & "raiserror ('xyz', 10, 127)")

Dim error
While not (rs is nothing)
    For Each error in conn.Errors
        MsgBox error.Description
    Next
    Set rs = rs.NextRecordSet
Wend
```

Comment: I know I'm reviving a long-dead thread, but this was very helpful for me. I had to update a badly-written legacy VbScript that feeds data into a SQL database, and even though I was trapping the `Err` object, I never saw any errors. Looks like I'll have to add this sort of error-checking to my SQL commands as well. Thanks!