# Excel VBA Recordset doesn't return data even though the stored procedure it's running does

Tags: excel, vba, sql-server-2019

I am working on some VBA code in Excel that is connecting to a SQL Server database. One of the modules is running three commands - one that uses a `CommandText` and two that are running stored procedures (neither of which has parameters).

This was working correctly until today. I updated one of the stored procedures because it wasn't returning the correct data and now, when I run the following code, the `ADORecordSet` has a state of closed after the call to `.Execute` so the call to `adoRs.EOF` throws an error

> 3704 - Operation is not allowed when the object is closed

```
With adoCm
    Set .ActiveConnection = adoConnect
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    
    .CommandText = "sp_XOL_DETAIL"
    Set adoRs = .Execute
        
    If Not adoRs.EOF Then
      Worksheets("Additional Detail (XOL)").Activate
      Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset adoRs
    End If
    adoRs.Close
  End With
```

All three calls to the database use the same `ADOConnection` (`adoConnect`), `ADOCommand` (`adoCm`), and `ADORecordSet` (`adoRS`).  The `ADORecordset` is closed after loading its data into the spreadsheet and before the `ADOCommand` is configured for the next query.

However, when I run the stored procedure in SSMS, it returns almost 1,000 rows of data.

- I have verified that the connection is open.
- I have tried creating a new `ADORecordSet` instead of using the one that the two previous queries have run in, but I get the same error.
- I tried changing the `.CommandType` to `adCmdText` and the `.CommandText` to `exec sp_XOL_DETAIL`, but I get the same error.

What might be causing this? Or what else should I look at to try to diagnose the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3013843/478884 shows how to check the `Connection.Errors` collection after the call to `Execute`.  That may provide some useful information in your case.

Comment: Make sure the proc has `SET NOCOUNT ON`. This will suppress DONE_IN_PROC (rowcount) messages that are returned to ADO as closed empty record sets.

Comment: **Side note**: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue - I needed to have "SET NOCOUNT ON;" at the top of the SP code.  After adding that and recompiling, everything is working correctly.