Error: 3704 Operation is not allowed when the object is closed for some records
I'm trying to run this piece of VBA code to get metadata from the PowerBI Rest API. For reference, I have other "Get" Functions with SQL queries in the same Module and they all work fine. However, when I run the below function I get two error messages:

GetDatasetTables Error: -1056112626 Method 'Open' of object '_Connection' failed

GetDatasetTables Error: 3704 Operation is not allowed when the object is closed


The function still extracts metadata from several reports but there's a lot of them that get the above errors and no data is extracted.
Private Sub GetDatasetTables(ByVal psWorkspaceID As String, ByVal psDatasetID As String, Optional ByVal psLocation As String = "us-north-central-c-primary")

On Error GoTo Err

    'Power BI variables
    Dim loPBIConn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim lsPBIConn As String
    Dim loPBIRS As Recordset
    Dim lsPBISQL As String
   
    'DB2 variables
    Dim loConn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim loCmd As ADODB.Command
    Dim lsCmdText As String
    
    WriteLog "Processing tables in dataset " & psDatasetID, , True
        
    'Other variables
    Dim lsout As String
      
    'connect to DB2 database
    Set loConn = New ADODB.Connection
    loConn.ConnectionString = GetDB2ConnectionString()
    loConn.ConnectionTimeout = 600
    loConn.Open
    
    'setup DB2 command
    Set loCmd = New ADODB.Command
    loCmd.ActiveConnection = loConn
    loCmd.CommandTimeout = 600
         
    'configure PBI connection string
    lsPBIConn = "Provider=MSOLAP.7;Integrated Security=SSPI;Data Source=https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api;;"
    lsPBIConn = lsPBIConn & "Initial Catalog=" & psDatasetID
    lsPBIConn = lsPBIConn & ";Location=https://wabi-" & psLocation & "-redirect.analysis.windows.net/xmla?vs=sobe_wowvirtualserver&"
    lsPBIConn = lsPBIConn & "db=" & psDatasetID
    lsPBIConn = lsPBIConn & ";MDX Compatibility= 1; MDX Missing Member Mode= Error; Safety Options= 2; Update Isolation Level= 2"
        
    'connect to PBI database
    Set loPBIConn = New ADODB.Connection
    loPBIConn.ConnectionString = lsPBIConn
    loPBIConn.ConnectionTimeout = 600
    loPBIConn.Open
        
    'Check if connection is open
    If loPBIConn.State = adStateOpen Then
    
        'table insert
        
        'create insert query
        Set loCmd = New ADODB.Command
        loCmd.ActiveConnection = loConn
        loCmd.CommandTimeout = 600

        'change to merge instead of delete->insert
        lsCmdText = "MERGE INTO a.dataset_table dest "
        lsCmdText = lsCmdText & "USING (VALUES('" & psWorkspaceID & "', '" & psDatasetID & "', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, CURRENT DATE)) "
        lsCmdText = lsCmdText & "AS src (workspace_id, dataset_id, table_name, table_type, table_description, table_olap_type, date_created, date_modified, updateddate) "
        lsCmdText = lsCmdText & "ON src.workspace_id = dest.workspace_id AND src.dataset_id = dest.dataset_id AND src.table_name = dest.table_name AND src.table_type = dest.table_type "
        lsCmdText = lsCmdText & "WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET dest.workspace_id = src.workspace_id, dest.dataset_id = src.dataset_id, dest.table_name = src.table_name, dest.table_type = src.table_type, dest.table_description = src.table_description, dest.table_olap_type = src.table_olap_type, dest.date_created = src.date_created, dest.date_modified = src.date_modified, dest.updateddate = src.updateddate "
        lsCmdText = lsCmdText & "WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (workspace_id, dataset_id, table_name, table_type, table_description, table_olap_type, date_created, date_modified, updateddate) VALUES (src.workspace_id, src.dataset_id, src.table_name, src.table_type, src.table_description, src.table_olap_type, src.date_created, src.date_modified, src.updateddate) "
                
        loCmd.CommandType = adCmdText
        loCmd.CommandText = lsCmdText
                
        loCmd.Parameters.Append loCmd.CreateParameter("table_name", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, "")
        loCmd.Parameters.Append loCmd.CreateParameter("table_type", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, "")
        loCmd.Parameters.Append loCmd.CreateParameter("table_description", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, "")
        loCmd.Parameters.Append loCmd.CreateParameter("table_olap_type", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, "")
        loCmd.Parameters.Append loCmd.CreateParameter("date_created", adDBTimeStamp)
        loCmd.Parameters.Append loCmd.CreateParameter("date_modified", adDBTimeStamp)
                
        'get PBI recordset - table

        lsPBISQL = "SELECT * FROM $SYSTEM.DBSCHEMA_TABLES WHERE [TABLE_TYPE] = 'TABLE' "
        Set loPBIRS = loPBIConn.Execute(lsPBISQL)
                 
        'For each row
        Do While Not loPBIRS.EOF
                    
            'check for unneeded column
            If InStr(1, Replace(loPBIRS("TABLE_NAME").Value & "", "$", ""), "DateTableTemplate", vbTextCompare) = 0 _
                And InStr(1, Replace(loPBIRS("TABLE_NAME").Value & "", "$", ""), "LocalDateTable", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            
                'set parameters
                loCmd.Parameters("table_name").Value = loPBIRS("TABLE_NAME").Value & ""
                loCmd.Parameters("table_type").Value = loPBIRS("TABLE_TYPE").Value & ""
                loCmd.Parameters("table_description").Value = loPBIRS("DESCRIPTION").Value & ""
                loCmd.Parameters("table_olap_type").Value = loPBIRS("TABLE_OLAP_TYPE").Value
                loCmd.Parameters("date_created").Value = loPBIRS("DATE_CREATED").Value
                loCmd.Parameters("date_modified").Value = loPBIRS("DATE_MODIFIED").Value
                
                'execute insert
                loCmd.Execute
            
            End If
                        
            'idle
            DoEvents
            
            'fetch next record
            loPBIRS.MoveNext
                
        Loop
                
        loPBIRS.Close

    
        'column insert
        
        'create insert query
        Set loCmd = New ADODB.Command
        loCmd.ActiveConnection = loConn
        loCmd.CommandTimeout = 600
        
        'change to merge instead of delete->insert
        lsCmdText = "MERGE INTO a.dataset_table_column dest "
        lsCmdText = lsCmdText & "USING (VALUES('" & psWorkspaceID & "', '" & psDatasetID & "', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, CURRENT DATE)) "
        lsCmdText = lsCmdText & "AS src (workspace_id, dataset_id, table_name, column_name, column_description, column_olap_type, data_type, char_max_length, numeric_precision, numeric_scale, updateddate) "
        lsCmdText = lsCmdText & "ON src.workspace_id = dest.workspace_id AND src.dataset_id = dest.dataset_id AND src.table_name = dest.table_name AND src.column_name = dest.column_name "
        lsCmdText = lsCmdText & "WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET dest.workspace_id = src.workspace_id, dest.dataset_id = src.dataset_id, dest.table_name = src.table_name, dest.column_name = src.column_name, dest.column_description = src.column_description, dest.column_olap_type = src.column_olap_type, dest.data_type = src.data_type, dest.char_max_length = src.char_max_length, dest.numeric_precision = src.numeric_precision, dest.numeric_scale = src.numeric_scale, dest.updateddate = src.updateddate "
        lsCmdText = lsCmdText & "WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (workspace_id, dataset_id, table_name, column_name, column_description, column_olap_type, data_type, char_max_length, numeric_precision, numeric_scale, updateddate) VALUES (src.workspace_id, src.dataset_id, src.table_name, src.column_name, src.column_description, src.column_olap_type, src.data_type, src.char_max_length, src.numeric_precision, src.numeric_scale, src.updateddate) "
        
        loCmd.CommandType = adCmdText
        loCmd.CommandText = lsCmdText
        
        loCmd.Parameters.Append loCmd.CreateParameter("table_name", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, "")
        loCmd.Parameters.Append loCmd.CreateParameter("column_name", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, "")
        loCmd.Parameters.Append loCmd.CreateParameter("column_description", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, "")
        loCmd.Parameters.Append loCmd.CreateParameter("column_olap_type", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, "")
        loCmd.Parameters.Append loCmd.CreateParameter("data_type", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, "")
        loCmd.Parameters.Append loCmd.CreateParameter("char_max_length", adInteger, , 0)
        loCmd.Parameters.Append loCmd.CreateParameter("numeric_precision", adSmallInt, , 0)
        loCmd.Parameters.Append loCmd.CreateParameter("numeric_scale", adSmallInt, , 0)
        
        
        
        'get PBI recordset - table

        lsPBISQL = "SELECT * FROM $SYSTEM.DBSCHEMA_COLUMNS WHERE [COLUMN_OLAP_TYPE] <> 'SCHEMA' "
        Set loPBIRS = loPBIConn.Execute(lsPBISQL)
        
        'For each row
        Do While Not loPBIRS.EOF
        
            'check for unneeded column
            If InStr(1, Replace(loPBIRS("COLUMN_NAME").Value & "", "$", ""), "RowNumber-", vbTextCompare) = 0 _
                And InStr(1, Replace(loPBIRS("TABLE_NAME").Value & "", "$", ""), "DateTableTemplate", vbTextCompare) = 0 _
                And InStr(1, Replace(loPBIRS("TABLE_NAME").Value & "", "$", ""), "LocalDateTable", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            
                'set parameters
                loCmd.Parameters("table_name").Value = loPBIRS("TABLE_NAME").Value & ""
                loCmd.Parameters("column_name").Value = loPBIRS("COLUMN_NAME").Value & ""
                loCmd.Parameters("column_description").Value = loPBIRS("DESCRIPTION").Value & ""
                loCmd.Parameters("column_olap_type").Value = loPBIRS("COLUMN_OLAP_TYPE").Value & ""
                loCmd.Parameters("data_type").Value = loPBIRS("DATA_TYPE").Value & ""
                loCmd.Parameters("char_max_length").Value = "0" & loPBIRS("CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH").Value
                loCmd.Parameters("numeric_precision").Value = "0" & loPBIRS("NUMERIC_PRECISION").Value & ""
                loCmd.Parameters("numeric_scale").Value = "0" & loPBIRS("NUMERIC_SCALE").Value
                
                'execute insert
                loCmd.Execute
                
            End If
                
            'idle
            DoEvents
            
            'fetch next record
            loPBIRS.MoveNext
            
        
        Loop    'Do While Not loPBIRS.EOF
        
        
        
        '-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        'schema insert
        
        'create insert query
        Set loCmd = New ADODB.Command
        loCmd.ActiveConnection = loConn
        loCmd.CommandTimeout = 600
        
        'change to merge instead of delete->insert
        lsCmdText = "MERGE INTO a.dataset_catalog dest "
        lsCmdText = lsCmdText & "USING (VALUES('" & psWorkspaceID & "', '" & psDatasetID & "', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, CURRENT DATE)) "
        lsCmdText = lsCmdText & "AS src (workspace_id, dataset_id, catalog_name, catalog_description, roles, date_modified, compatability_level, catalog_type, catalog_version, date_queried, currently_used, popularity, weightedpopularity, updateddate) "
        lsCmdText = lsCmdText & "ON src.workspace_id = dest.workspace_id AND src.dataset_id = dest.dataset_id AND src.catalog_name = dest.catalog_name "
        lsCmdText = lsCmdText & "WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET dest.workspace_id = src.workspace_id, dest.dataset_id = src.dataset_id, dest.catalog_name = src.catalog_name, dest.catalog_description = src.catalog_description, dest.roles = src.roles, dest.date_modified = src.date_modified, dest.compatability_level = src.compatability_level, dest.catalog_type = src.catalog_type, dest.catalog_version = src.catalog_version, dest.date_queried = src.date_queried, dest.currently_used = src.currently_used, dest.popularity = src.popularity, dest.weightedpopularity = src.weightedpopularity, dest.updateddate = src.updateddate "
        lsCmdText = lsCmdText & "WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (workspace_id, dataset_id, catalog_name, catalog_description, roles, date_modified, compatability_level, catalog_type, catalog_version, date_queried, currently_used, popularity, weightedpopularity, updateddate) VALUES (src.workspace_id, src.dataset_id, src.catalog_name, src.catalog_description, src.roles, src.date_modified, src.compatability_level, src.catalog_type, src.catalog_version, src.date_queried, src.currently_used, src.popularity, src.weightedpopularity, src.updateddate) "
       
        loCmd.CommandType = adCmdText
        loCmd.CommandText = lsCmdText
        
        loCmd.Parameters.Append loCmd.CreateParameter("catalog_name", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, "")
        loCmd.Parameters.Append loCmd.CreateParameter("catalog_description", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, "")
        loCmd.Parameters.Append loCmd.CreateParameter("roles", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, "")
        loCmd.Parameters.Append loCmd.CreateParameter("date_modified", adDBTimeStamp)
        loCmd.Parameters.Append loCmd.CreateParameter("compatability_level", adSmallInt, , 0)
        loCmd.Parameters.Append loCmd.CreateParameter("catalog_type", adSmallInt, , 0)
        loCmd.Parameters.Append loCmd.CreateParameter("catalog_version", adSmallInt, , 0)
        loCmd.Parameters.Append loCmd.CreateParameter("date_queried", adDBTimeStamp)
        loCmd.Parameters.Append loCmd.CreateParameter("currently_used", adSmallInt, , 0)
        loCmd.Parameters.Append loCmd.CreateParameter("popularity", adSingle, , 0)
        loCmd.Parameters.Append loCmd.CreateParameter("weightedpopularity", adDouble, , 0)
        
        'get PBI recordset - table

        lsPBISQL = "SELECT * FROM $SYSTEM.DBSCHEMA_CATALOGS "
        Set loPBIRS = loPBIConn.Execute(lsPBISQL)
        
        'For each row
        Do While Not loPBIRS.EOF
        
            'set parameters
            loCmd.Parameters("catalog_name").Value = loPBIRS("CATALOG_NAME").Value & ""
            loCmd.Parameters("catalog_description").Value = loPBIRS("DESCRIPTION").Value & ""
            loCmd.Parameters("roles").Value = loPBIRS("ROLES").Value & ""
            loCmd.Parameters("date_modified").Value = loPBIRS("DATE_MODIFIED").Value
            loCmd.Parameters("compatability_level").Value = "0" & loPBIRS("COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL").Value
            loCmd.Parameters("catalog_type").Value = "0" & loPBIRS("TYPE").Value
            loCmd.Parameters("catalog_version").Value = "0" & loPBIRS("VERSION").Value
            loCmd.Parameters("date_queried").Value = loPBIRS("DATE_QUERIED").Value
            loCmd.Parameters("currently_used").Value = loPBIRS("CURRENTLY_USED").Value
            loCmd.Parameters("popularity").Value = "0" & loPBIRS("POPULARITY").Value
            loCmd.Parameters("weightedpopularity").Value = "0" & loPBIRS("WEIGHTEDPOPULARITY").Value
            
            'execute insert
            loCmd.Execute
                
                
            'idle
            DoEvents
            
            'fetch next record
            loPBIRS.MoveNext
            
        
        Loop    'Do While Not loPBIRS.EOF
             
        'close connections
        loPBIRS.Close
        loConn.Close
    
    End If
        
    'close connection
    loPBIConn.Close
    
    Exit Sub

Err:

    'prevent errors
    If Err.Number = 91 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Debug.Print "GetDatasetTables Error: " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
    WriteLog "GetDatasetTables Error: " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description, "Dataset: " & psDatasetID
    Resume Next

End Sub

Thanks in advance.

If you comment out the error handler you can tell us exactly where it fails...

I commented it out and it pointed me to the "loPBIConn.Open" line. I also got the same error but for another function and another error: The statement failed because the authorization ID does not have the required authorization or privilege to perform the operation.  Operation: "INSERT". I'll get an insert access and hope it solves the issue. Thanks, Tim.

I don't have any idea about the PowerBI provider, but maybe see if there's any more information in the Connection.Errors collection after the Open call fails.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/errors-collection-ado?view=sql-server-ver16   For example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013447/how-to-retrieve-all-errors-and-messages-from-a-query-using-ado
